# Calculating the range of a function

Tags: functions

How would one calculate the range of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1}$, with $x > 3$?

And how would you generally calculate the range of any asymptotic graph in the form $1/x$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\infty>x>3\iff \infty>x-1>2$$

As $x-1>0,$
$$0=\frac1{\infty}<\frac 1{x-1}<\frac12$$

Comment: how would you use this info to find range?

Comment: What more info do you need? the range is between 1/2 and 0

Comment: @user149550, this $(0,\frac12)$ is the range

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee the answer in my book is 0 <f(x) < 1/4 im not quite sure how they got that